# How to alert the path name in the alert box in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

My task is to alert the path name in a alert box which we select or upload using file upload button after selecting the or uploading the file the alert box should alert the path name.

Here is my HTML page, index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
<input type="file" id="file"  name="file">  
 <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <p>{{data}}</p>
</div>



<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function ProductCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'none';
    $scope.add = function(){
    alert(file);
      var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],

          r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function(e){
        $scope.data = e.target.result;

      }
      r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And my plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/5xawn6e51QzZfDt86zwQ?p=preview

Comment: hey you have written alert(file).but where did you define it.There is no variable with file.Try doing alert(f)

Comment: If i do that so im getting undifined in a alert box

Answer (score 0):

Hey Anil I have made a plunker check this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function ProductCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'none';
    $scope.add = function(){

      var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],

          r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function(e){
        $scope.data = e.target.result;

            alert(JSON.stringify(f));
      }
      r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
```

### `http://plnkr.co/edit/bU5GWkkGISF9niWbxIXC?p=preview

Comment: But i need only  the path name to be alerted.....plz help me wit this since im new to algular js